# How can I get all RelatedManagers from a particular Django Model instance?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say I have a set of Django Models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    content = models.TextField(default='', blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    score = models.ForeignKey('Score', blank=True, null=True)
    points = models.ManyToManyField('Points')


class Score(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)


class Points(models.Model):
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
```

And now I somehow get an instance of a `Score` model (without actually knowing that this is `Score` model) and an instance of `Points` model (again, without knowing that this is `Points` model):

```
>>> type(s)
<class 'myapp.models.Score'>
>>> type(p)
<class 'myapp.models.Points'>
```

Now I can get access to a set of related `Article` instances via the following code:

```
>>> s.article_set
<django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager object at 0x10d1e8610>
>>> p.article_set
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x10d1e8850>
```

But this is the case where I know actual DB schema and I know that attributes are called `article_set`. In my case I **do not know** the actual DB scema. And I want to get all the RelatedManager attributes of the current model instance.

I think that it is possible to implement this via `._meta` attribute but I didn't manage to do that while trying. So I would probably need an actual working example of something like `get_related_managers(self)` method implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
def get_related_managers(self):
    managers = []
    for related_object in self._meta.get_all_related_objects():
        managers.append(getattr(self, related_object.get_accessor_name()))
    return managers
```

You will also have to loop through `self._meta.get_all_related_many_to_many_objects()` if you want many to manys as well.

**UPD:** In newer django versions, `_meta` does not have such methods, but the same can be done with `self._meta.related_objects` and `self._meta.many_to_many`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have somehow missed this one while discovering `_meta` property.

Comment: No problem. Was hoping there was a better way to do this, as non-public attributes (attributes with leading underscore, e.g. `_meta`) are "not intended to be used by third parties; [and it is not] guaranteed[d] that non-public attributes won't change or even be removed." (from http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). But I couldn't see a better way to do this.

Comment: Actually, there is a lot of things you cannot do with standard Django model API and that are done only via `_meta` attribute. Sometimes, Django really sucks :)